# Does it make sense to use R to read in and search through extremely large CSV file?

Tags: python, r, database, csv

I have a CSV file with approximately 700 columns and 10,000 rows.  Each of these columns contains attribute information for the object in column 1 of each row.  I would like to search through this "database" for specific records that match a set of requirements based on their attribute information.

For instance, one column contains state information in the 2 letter abbreviation form.  Another column might contain an acronym referring to a certain geographic characteristic.  Suppose I'm looking for all rows where the state is NY, and the acronym in GRG.

What packages should I use to handle this work/data anlaysis in R?

If there are no good packages in R, for handling such a large dataset, what should I look to using?

I am familiar with R, Python, Office and some SQL commands.

Edit:  I am not going to modify the dataset, but record (print out or create a subset from) the results of the querying.  I'll have a total of 10-12 queries at first to determine if this dataset truly serves my need. But I may possibly have hundreds of queries later - at which point I'd like to switch from manual querying of the dataset to an automated querying (if possible).

Comment: Do you intend to modify and save this data set?  Are you primarily interested in data analysis, or do you plan to use the data set in an enterprise environment?

Comment: If you are going to be doing this often, and have access to a linux/mac machine, I would suggest learning/using awk on the command line.

Comment: This looks like a perfect job for sqlite, either standalone (`sqlite> .mode csv; sqlite> .import C:/work/somedata.csv tab1`) or within R with `library( "RSQLite" )`

Comment: @ReubenL. even if you don't have a linux/mac machine, awk and such tools are easily installable on Windows via cygwin, and are essential data science tools. awk, grep, sed and friends.

Comment: I'm trying to reword this to keep it open since two people have favorited it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the fread option from the data.table package

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf

or you can import the data in an RDBMS and connect to it using RODBC

http://www.statmethods.net/input/dbinterface.html

or you can use RevoScaleR package from Revolution Analytics

or you can use the cloud to process the data

or you can use ff package

based on your querying needs- data.table package is the best
you can use setKey to set the index

Answer (score 2):

Depending how much data is in each column and if you're planning to do statistical analysis, I would definitely go with R. If no analysis then python with pandas is a good solution. Do not use office for those files, it'll give you a headache.

If you're brave and your data is going to increase, implement MongoDB with either R or python depending on previous need.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load the whole file into memory I suggest using python library [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

You can enable "iterator=True" and then load the file chunk by chunk into memory and loop through each chunk to do your analysis.
If you need any other information, please let me know.